# open cv module cannot be imported

Tags: python, opencv

While importing OpenCV python by the code below

```
 import cv2
```

I can't import the module instead it gives me an error.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "C:\Users\2684j\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have tried many ways and I have found an exact problem

here below I have given the steps clearly to solve this problem

1. first navigate to your python folder
2. then navigate further to Lib\site packages\cv2..
3. then create an folder name cv2 **do not change the folder name create a folder with cv2 as its name**
4. leaving the `_init_.py` file copy all other files into the cv2 folder **do not just copy just perform an cut copy paste action**

this is the exact way to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```